# Adding a <span> to widget title in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget, title, html

I am trying to change the color of the first word in the widget title in wordpress. I am using WP v.3.7.1 and a custom child theme that I created off of the twentythirteen theme.

I just need to wrap the first word in a  and can style it from there. I tried to add the following code to the function.php but it only works for one of the three widgets that I have. I have tried other widgets and it doesn't work either.

```
add_filter ('widget_title', 'wpzoom_fix_widgets');

function wpzoom_fix_widgets($old_title) {

    $title = explode(" ", $old_title,2);

    $titleNew = "<span>$title[0]</span> $title[1]";

    return $titleNew;

}
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the first answer on [WordPress Answsers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82312/insert-a-span-inside-widget-title-to-give-a-different-color-to-the-second-word), it looks close to what you are looking for:

```
add_filter('widget_title', my_title);

function my_title($title) {
    // Cut the title to 2 parts
    $title_parts = explode(' ', $title, 2);

    // Throw first word inside a span
    $title = '<span class="my_class">'.$title_parts[0].'</span>';

    // Add the remaining words if any
    if(isset($title_parts[1]))
        $title .= ' '.$title_parts[1];

    return $title;
}
```

Good luck :)

Comment: That is very similar and works as well. The problem is that I want 2 widgets that pull from different groups of categories for recent posts. If I use the standard WP recent posts the code works but will pull in all posts. I want one for News and the other for Community work that the client is doing. I have tried Advanced Recent Posts, Flexible Recent Posts, & TW Recent Posts and none of them work with this code. Flexible Recent Posts would be the preferred plugin. Any other suggestions? Any reason why none of the plugins would work with this code (ie its processed before the widget is loaded)?

Comment: Each of these plugins use their own custom template system that overrides the WordPress template.  With Flexible Recent Posts for instance when you place the widget into the widget area in the WordPress Admin screen you are given a mini html editor to create your own custom widget template for all the posts that will be shown by in the area.  You will need to use this tool to create your own custom template.

Comment: I kinda feel like a bonehead but it worked. I was obsessed with getting the title from the actual title box to work and I overlooked the fact that I could just leave it blank and add the code to the editor in the widget. Thanks!

Comment: Lol - we all have those days :)  That's why its great to have other folks to talk to that can help us with our perspective.  Good luck with your project.